# Can I overwrite default WordPress Json API For no more pages text

Tags: rest-api, api

When I call Json API, when there is no more pagination, the response text is ***The page number requested is larger than the number of pages available.***

I would like to change that text to custom text and also I would like to translate that text to other language. So, is there any way to change that text?

Comment: Probably, but if I were you I wouldn't present that message to your end user anyway: look for the error code (rest_post_invalid_page_number?) and show your own message.

Comment: Rup is right, generally these messages are intended for a developer. You’re better off checking for the code and presenting your own message. But I’d go one step further and say that you would ideally be coding your application so that it knows when the last page is, and so it doesn’t let the user query a page that doesn’t exist. All the necessary information for doing this is in the response headers.